# mysql stored procedure declare statment not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

BELOW IS MY STORED PROCEDURE AND THAT PROBLEM IS COMING ON declare line .

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadRelationSystem(IN tablename VARCHAR(150),IN fieldvalue INT(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE tabname VARCHAR(150);
SET tabname = tablename;
SELECT * FROM table where fieldtable = tabname;
END
delimiter;
```

Comment: "Not working" is not an explanation. You need to post the **exact** error message you get, or if you don't get an error describe exactly what are the expected result and the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to declare a variablem just use it directly:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadRelationSystem
(IN tablename VARCHAR(150), IN fieldvalue INT(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM `table` where fieldtable = tablename;
END //
delimiter;
```